# Create route without path [Symfony3]

Tags: php, symfony

In security.yml in firewall/main/form_login I have this:

```
default_target_path: after_login
always_use_default_target_path: true
```

I want to create a route named after_login, but without a path, but symfony redirects me to homepage after login.

```
/**
 * @Route(name="after_login")
 */
public function afterloginAction()
```

I want to nobody have access to this controller's method.

Is it possible to create such route or maybe another way to redirect after login to this method?

Comment: Did you run `./bin/console debug:router`? Your route needs to be listed there. It needs a $path to work correctly

Answer (score 2):

> I want to add some variables to session but only once after login.

Best way approaching this would be listen on the `security.interactive_login` event:

default_target_path is not meant for that. That is just an redirect to an controller action, the user profile for example.

Using an controller action once and then make it not-accessible by setting a session key would be an ugly hack.

Read https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events for that purpose. Using an event listener would make it hidden form the outside world automatically.

Comment: That method is to add some variables to session but only once after login. I do not want to give any user to access it to avoid any errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with @Route. Is there wrong something here, why you want it?

Comment: I want to add some variables to session but only once after login.

Comment: okay, add a path and required login for enter this path. if current user have not session variables set and redirect. if current user have session variables redirect again.

Comment: Edited my answer